# What Redmine plugin allows quick navigation between projects?

Tags: search, plugins, navigation, project, redmine

Is there a redmine plugin that allows quick navigation between projects?

Feature it might have may be showing a pop up dialog that allows you to see all your projects at a glance and jump to them, or the time that gives a filtered list as you type the name?

Answer (score 0):

How about the built-in project drop-down list?

Here's how I use it with FireFox (windows) - no mouse needed:

- `shift` + `alt` + `f` : puts the focus in the search box
- `tab` : moves focues to the project drop-down
- ... start typing the name of your project (usually the first 2-3 letters are enough)
- `tab` or `enter` to go to the project

Last time I checked, there was no accesskey defined for the project drop-down, hence using the one for the search box.

Comment: I have more projects than are usually shown in the list and you can't type in it.

Comment: How many projects? I didn't know that redmine will not list all projects if there are too many. I can't actually type in the drop-down neither, but the correct entry gets selected as I type - standard behavior of a dropdown select.

Comment: It only responds to the key and does not allow filter on the keystrokes you enter like browsers do. I have come across this plugin https://github.com/wojtha/projects_tree_view and if it works I'll award myself the answer :)